# Using Conan to build multiple libraries and packaging them to be used without Conan

Tags: python, c++, cmake, conan

I am very new to Conan and I am quite lost in the documentation at the moment and I cannot really find a way to do what I want.

Maybe I am not using the right tool for this, I am very open to suggestions.

Let's say my C++ project needs opencv and nlohmann_json to be built.
I want to be able to create an archive of all my project's dependencies to be used as is, so it can be redistributed on our gitlab instance.

I want to have a repository which roughly looks like this:

```sh
├── conanfile.py
├── json
│   └── 3.10.4
│       └── conanfile.py
└── opencv
    ├── 4.4.0
    │   └── conanfile.py
    └── 5.1.0
        └── conanfile.py
```

Where invoking the root conanfile.py would automatically build the required libs and copy their files as to have something like this:

```
├── conanfile.py
├── json
│   └── 3.10.4
│       └── conanfile.py
├── opencv
│   ├── 4.4.0
│   │   └── conanfile.py
│   └── 5.1.0
│       └── conanfile.py
└── win64_x86
    ├── include
    │   ├── nlohmann
    │   └── opencv2
    └── lib
        └── <multiple files>
```

and the CI/CD would archive the directory and make it available for download.

I have managed to build and package a very simple repo (https://github.com/jameskbride/cmake-hello-world) independently using the git tools and doing something like this:

```py
    def config_options(self):
        if self.settings.os == "Windows":
            del self.options.fPIC

    def source(self):
        git = tools.Git(folder="repo")
        git.clone("https://github.com/jameskbride/cmake-hello-world", "master")

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure(source_folder="repo")
        cmake.build()
```

However, I cannot figure out how to get the files that I want to package from my main conanfile.py. All of the approaches I have tried so far needed the package to be built separately (ie, going to the folder, using `conan source .` `conan build .` and `conan export-pkg .`. I am, 100% sure I am not doing this properly but I can't really find a way to do this. I found something about `deploy()` in the docs but can't figure out how to use it...

**NB: I would really, really prefer not using a remote with prebuilt binaries for dependencies. I want to build everything from source with the CMake configurations I have defined.
I also explicitely don't want a conan package in the end. I just want an aggregation of all the files needed to be shipped directly to the machines.**

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to fetch binaries from a third party remote like ConanCenter, or that you never want to store your compiled binaries? Why would you want to rebuild again and again from sources exactly the same binary? Of course you are building everything from sources, but not unnecessarily repeating the exact same build.

Comment: For extracting files from Conan packages and aggregating them, you want to use the ``imports`` feature. Existing both in conanfile.txt as ``[imports]`` and as ``imports()`` method. If you want a full copy of the package contents, the ``-g deploy`` generator will also do that.

Comment: I just don't want to fetch from a third party yes. I will cache the builds, I just want to build them from source myself. Thank you, I will look into ``imports``.

Comment: One thing I am not sure is how to define a recipe for a package. Let's take opencv for example. I want version 4.4.0 specifically, and I want to define build options. How do I do this ?

Comment: Update: I have been messing with Conan for a few hours now and it turns out: I didn't have a clue what I was doing. I understand the flow a bit more now, and I am able to do pretty much what I wanted. Thanks a lot, sorry for the mess.

Comment: I'd recommend to follow some sections in the docs, like https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/getting_started.html, which are tutorial-like, or the free training courses in https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/training_courses.html (hands-on, self-paced video courses), can help giving a quick understanding of the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered by Conan's co-founder james here: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/9874

Basically:

- Use the CMakeDeps generator instead of cmake / cmake_find_package
- Patch the resulting cmake config files at install time inside the generate() method from the main conanfile.py
- Edit recipes accordingly (but should be fine most of the time)